# Converting Video Uploads for HTML5 in Chrome

Tags: .net, html, video, html5-video

I am creating a CMS where users can upload videos for display on pages.

When a video is uploaded, I create a background task (using [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)) to convert the video into MP4, OGV and WEBM.

I am running the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome on my development machine.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video), these browsers should fully support H.264 (MP4), Theora (OGG) and VP8/VP9 (WEBM).

Everything seems to work as expected in Firefox and locally using VLC Media Player.  However, with Chrome, when I try to convert an existing video (which is an MP4 with H.264 Video and MPEG-2/4 Audio) into the three required formats for HTML5 video, I am getting dramatically different results.

### Libraries

Using [MediaToolkit](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit) and [NReco.VideoConverter](https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx), the resulting MP4 and OGG/OGV file is not playable in Chrome (Although WEBM is working).  This is my implementation:

```
// MediaToolkit
using (var engine = new Engine())
{
    engine.Convert(new MediaFile("C:\SourceFile.mp4"), new MediaFile("C:\DestinationFile.mp4"));
}
// NReco.VideoConverter
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia("C:\SourceFile.mp4", "C:\DestinationFile.mp4", Format.mp4);
```

The resulting mp4 does not work in Chrome despite seeming to have the same codec.  Here are the details of the original and converted files:

#### Working Original Upload

VIDEO

- Codec: H.264/AVC
- Bitrate: 3954 kbps
- Frame Size: 1920 x 1080 pixels
- Frame Rate: 29.97 fps

  AUDIO
- Codec: MPEG-2/4 Audio
- Sample Rate: 44100 Hz 16 bit
- Sample Size: 16 bit
- Bitrate: 125.82 kbps
- Channels: 2

#### Non-Working Video after Conversion

VIDEO

- Codec: H.264/AVC
- Frame Size: 1920 x 1080 pixels
- Frame Rate: 29.97 fps
- Bitrate: 1909 kbps

AUDIO

- Codec: MPEG-2/4 Audio
- Sample Rate: 44100 Hz
- Sample Size: 16 bit
- Bitrate: 124.81 kbps
- Channels: 2

As you can see, the input and output files appear to be identical.  However, the output simply does not work in Chrome.

### Online Converters

- When I try [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/mp4-to-mp4), the resulting MP4 does not work.
- When I try [Converter Point](http://converterpoint.com/), the MP4 and WEBM works but the OGV does not.
- When I try [Online Convert](http://www.online-convert.com/), the MP4 and WEBM works but the OGV does not.

Why is this process so difficult? Am I missing an easy solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats Probably an unsupported format.

Comment: But the format of the original and the newly converted video is the same when i look at it's properties..

Comment: So MP4, OGV, and WebM are container formats. They just specify where in the file the video and audio information is located (among other things). The video and audio have their own formats, like H.264 or VP9 for video, or MP3 or AAC for audio. All of these need to be in the correct place for the video element to work. Each browser has implemented different combinations of formats, just to make our jobs easier ;). I'm not sure what your conversion process is or how your CMS shows video, and frankly, this really isn't about programming at all. Research "browser video codecs" for more info.

Comment: Hi @MikeMcCaughan - I used AVS Video Converter to look at the Video/Audio codecs and they look identical (see update above).  Is there a way of going deeper to see why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Can you provide links to example before and after videos?

Comment: Hi @Mick - here is a video of me playing the original one and then attempting to play the converted one:https://www.screencast.com/t/rHzxxuVAIC

Comment: Actually I meant links to the actual before and after videos - this allows people check the format in detail.

Comment: Hi @Mick - ahh that makes sense - here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c2ndfsms49stwc4/AAB10WBPf0keb5NxU3_Q9oyRa?dl=0

Comment: I just tried both and they played fine - no errors in the browser console on Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Did you just open them directly in Chrome (e.g. file:/// in windows at least)?  This works fine for me as well.  I am opening them as part of an ASP.NET MVC website - (so when I access them it is like this: http://member.dev:32939/Content/Files/17022892450713DE834BE186B70337E6BE3A0C.mp4)

Comment: I opened them locally and also played them from dropbox which probably just HTTP streamed them. It sounds like your issue may be with the hosting streaming rather than the mp4s themselves. The link 'member.dev...' link is local btw, I think so no visible here.